Org babel R sessions setwd value
If I make a new org file:
#+begin_src R
  getwd()
#+end_src


#+begin_src R :session
  getwd()
#+end_src

When I execute the first block, I do not get asked for the "R starting project directory" but I do in the second block.
I am confused to where the value I enter for the R starting project directory is stored and how to reset it?
If I set the value for this org file then if I close the file and close emacs and reopen it still does not ask me for it again it just remembers what I entered last time. I want to change this value for an existing org file I do not know how to do this other then making a new org file and answering the question differntly. 
info:
GNU Emacs 29.3 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0, NS appkit-2113.60
Version 12.6.6 (Build 21G646)) of 2024-03-24
On Mac os
It might be something to do with Git and ESS?
I tried to trace (following chatgpt instrucions):
org-babel-execute-src-block:
Run M-x debug-on-entry RET org-babel-execute-src-block RET.
I then saw:
* ess--project-root((vc Git "~/Documents/sc_pd_ras_dop/"))

Which is the dir that it is defaulting to, by inserting :
setwd('~/Documents/sc_pd_ras_dop')

In the R buffer.
I think these variables might also be relevant?
If I open my org file which does not ask for the dir and try and describe the vars I get:
ess-ask-for-ess-directory nil
ess-startup-directory t
UPDATE
I think I was mistaken above. The issue I am having with sessions seems to do with setting a dir in the src code block.
if I have:
#+begin_src R :session new
  getwd()
#+end_src

I get prompted for my R starting project directory
if I have:
#+begin_src R :session new :dir "~"
  getwd()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/myusername

Which is my home dir
but if I have:
#+begin_src R :session new :dir "."
  getwd()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/myusername/Documents/myproject

Which is maybe the project dir that ess is getting because of git?
my org file is located in
/Users/myusername/Documents/myproject/scripts/org

so I think it is defaulting to the project-dir from ess.
if I have
#+begin_src R :session new :dir "./scripts"
  getwd()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/myusername/Documents/myproject

and if i have
#+begin_src R :session new :dir "scripts"
  getwd()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/myusername/Documents/myproject

But If i have
#+begin_src R :dir .
  getwd()
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: /Users/myusername/Documents/myproject/scripts/org

That is without a session it seems to do what I expect

You need to describe your setup more extensively: what starting project directory are you talking about? If I add these two blocks to a file in /tmp, I can run them both and they both produce /tmp without asking me anything. IOW, the only thing that matters AFAICS is the directory where the Org mode file is located.

I have tried to add some more relevant info.

What are the values of the variables?

ess-ask-for-ess-directory nil
ess-startup-directory t
I guess these are linked to differnt buffers somehow?
